# IDE to edit/modify native C/C++ files in Android Source code

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-source

I have been having tough time in finding a IDE or Editor which can help me easily modify the Android's C/C++ classes (mainly the classes under frameworks/base/core/jni)?

All the sites point to using Eclipse for development. But the dependencies were not resolved for C/C++ files. Java related dependencies are correctly resolved and the project is good enough to view the source files without any errors.

Right now, I just browse the C/C++ code in Eclipse CDT and make changes, compile using regular AOSP make commands and push it to my custom ROM. I am working on device drivers related work, so cannot use Emulator to test the changes :(

Two queries:

1. Is there a way, I can get content assist for Native C/C++ code for Android Source code ?
2. Is there any easy way to edit/build/run the native libraries quickly on Device ?

Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. You build AOSP from terminal, but use IDE for browse/edit/debug sessions.

What worked for me is creating a big eclipse C/C++ project containing everything under frameworks/base. Use it for browsing/editing/debugging using all the helpers that eclipse provides.

Please check [Debugging Android native applications](http://apienthusiast.blogspot.com/2014/07/debugging-android-native-applications.html) to understand AOSP debugging.

Answer (score -1):

I also have this problem! My solution is to re-set NDK path in "local.properties".

When i use default ndk path (ex: ndk.dir=C:\Users\%user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle sdk.dir=C:\Users\%user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk ) , I will have the same problem. So I download other NDK (from google official web-site) ,and set "ndk.dir", and I sloved.

You can try it~ maybe helpful for you.

ps. I use NDK version:14 , will happen this. I use v13 or v12 will solved.